# Bulk Mail through Outlook 365 Add-in

Tags: email, outlook, office365, outlook-addin

Have been search through Outlook dev center and other Microsoft dev sites and I am not able to find an actual answer to this.  Is it possible to create an addin for Outlook365/Outlook 2016 that would enable <strike>mail merging</strike> bulk mail from just that app?  I have found an application similar to what I would like called Tout but it involves installing a program and then using their site.  I would like to stay self contained in Outlook.

Thanks

Edit: To clarify the question I would like to know if I have a message, like a company letter, is it possible to send it to the whole team/contact list with it seeming like an individual email to each person? I would like to be able to do this from a couple buttons on my add-in.

Comment: You could look at this sample on how to do it with Excel JS and Microsoft Graph: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-TypeScript-MailMerge

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for an add in to add and remove recipients from an email via the js APIs, see [Office.context.mailbox.item.to/cc/bcc](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.item.html). There are also Excel APIs that would allow you to read data from an Excel sheet stored in Office 365, as one potential source of those addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you mean by bulk mail? Do you want the add-in to send mail in bulk from a generated list of contacts? The Office.context.mailbox.item.to/cc/bcc like what Igaud said above will allow you to specify the recipients of the mail. 
You can also explore these snippets if you would like to go the Microsoft Graph route: https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-Win-Snippets

Comment: I updated the question if that provides any extra clarification.